# Oracle kill inactive sessions stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I would like to write kill_inactive sessions stored procedure for Oracle.
something like

```
create or replace procedure kill_inactive_sessions as
begin
for rec in (select sid, serial# from sys.v_$session where status = 'INACTIVE') 
loop 
    execute immediate 'alter system kill session '''|| rec.sid || ',' || rec.serial# || ''' IMMEDIATE'; 
end loop; 
end kill_inactive_sessions;
```

Previous doesn't work (table or view does not exists).
But next select is working perfectly for the same user:

```
select sid, serial# from sys.v_$session where status = 'INACTIVE';
```

What I'm missing?

Comment: First, define, "doesn't work".  Does it throw an error?  What error?  Does it not do something that you expect it to do?  Second, why on earth would you want to do this?  Do you realize that most sessions are inactive the vast majority of the time?  You'll be killing every session that isn't running a SQL statement at that particular instant.  That's going to cause a massive number of users to get errors and immediately log right back in.

Comment: I'm limited with count of user connections. I'm pretty sure that after non graceful shutdown of my application most of sessions will not be used (after running unit tests, application is just killed). So I'm trying to free sessions that are not going to be used anymore.

Comment: How are you "limited with count of user connections"?  Are you referring to some sort of database limit?  I assume your application is a three-tiered application so the "non graceful shutdown" means that the application server crashed.  In general, I'd enable dead connection detection in the database so that the database can clean up connections where the client has terminated more efficiently.  In the specific case, though, surely you'd only want to terminate sessions for a particular user, though, not all inactive users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ORA-00942: table or view does not exist error almost certainly indicates that your access to the `v$session` view is via a role rather than a direct grant.

If you want to write a definer's rights stored procedure, the owner of the procedure must have the necessary privileges granted directly to the user, not via a role (and remember that `DBA` is just another role).  Most likely, if you disabled roles in your session, the `SELECT` statement outside of the procedure would not work.  In SQL*Plus, for example

```
SQL> set role none;
SQL> select sid, serial# from sys.v_$session where status = 'INACTIVE';
```

will likely throw the same ORA-00942 error.  Assuming it does, you need to grant the user that owns the stored procedure privileges directly.  For example

```
GRANT SELECT ANY DICTIONARY
   TO user_that_owns_the_procedure;
```

The same thing will also apply to the `ALTER SYSTEM` command that you are building and running.  The owner of the stored procedure will need to have privileges to run that command via a direct grant not via a role.

All that said, a procedure that kills all inactive sessions is highly problematic.  The vast majority of sessions are going to be inactive the vast majority of the time.  That doesn't mean that they should be killed.  Even if you're cleaning up after an application server crash, you really ought to be applying some additional predicates (for example, looking for sessions from a particular machine that are logged in as a particular user that were established before the application server crashed).  Long-term, though, I'd suggest [enabling dead connection detection](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/oraclenetdcd-2179641.pdf) so that the database can automatically take care of closing sessions when the client process dies unexpectedly.